# I want to change ",';" to "';" in shell script

Tags: bash, shell-script

I want to change `,';` to `';` in a shell script. But using `'` is a problem.

Comment: Can you give us some detail of exactly what you are trying to do?

Comment: Hey Stephen Rauch .. I was facing problem in a sed condition.. i was using sed 's/,';/';/g'.. Now i had solved the problem using sed "s/,';/';/g' .. Thanx anyway... sir

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried

```
sed -e "s/,';/';/"
```

because that seemed to work when I tried. (I would agree to usually single-quote the expression, but in your case, it does not contain anything that particularly needs protecting from shell expansions.)